# Discriminant divisor $\mathcal{D}_{r} \subseteq H^{0}(X,K_{X}^{\otimes r})$ is irreducible

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, line-bundles

Let $X\colon$ smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$, $K_{X}\colon$ canonical line bundle over $X$, and $W_{r}$ denotes $H^{0}(X,K_{X}^{\otimes r})$.

I'm trying to prove the following proposition,

> $\mathcal{D}_{r}=\{s_{r}\in W_{r}\mid \exists x\in X s.t. \operatorname{Div}(s_{r})\geq 2x\}\subseteq W_{r}$ is irreducible.

Consider $\Gamma_{r}\subseteq W_{r}\times X$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
\Gamma_{r}=\{(s_{r},x)\mid \operatorname{Div}(s_{r})\geq 2x\}
\end{equation*}
Then, $\mathcal{D}_{r}=pr_{W_{r}}(\Gamma_{r})$ ($pr_{W_{r}}\colon W_{r}\times X\rightarrow W_{r}$ is a natural projection). So, it suffices to show $\Gamma_{r}$ is irreducible.

Moreover, there is a natural $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ action on $W_{r}$, this action is extended trivially to $W_{r}\times X$, and $\Gamma{r}$ is $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$-equivariant with respect to this action. Thus this reduces to showing that $\mathbb{P}(\Gamma_{R})\subseteq \mathbb{P}(W_{r})\times X$ is irreducible.

I want to apply the following lemma to $pr_{X}\colon \mathbb{P}(\Gamma_{r})\rightarrow X$,

> Let $f\colon Y\rightarrow Z$ be a proper map between algebraic varieties. If $Z$ is irreducible, the general fiber is irreducible and all fibers are equidimensional then $Y$ is irreducible.

My text says that $\operatorname{codim}(pr_{X}^{-1}(x),\mathbb{P}(\Gamma_{r}))=2$ for every $x\in X$ by Riemann-Roch and $pr_{X}^{-1}(x)\subseteq \mathbb{P}(W_{r})$ is a linear subspace, and hence all fibers of $pr_{X}$ are equidimensional and irreducible.

But I don't understand why $\operatorname{codim}(pr_{X}^{-1}(x),\mathbb{P}(\Gamma_{r}))=2$ holds, and how to deduce that all fibers of $pr_{X}$ are equidimensional and irreducible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fiber of $\Gamma _r$ over $x\in X$ is  $H^0(K_X^r(-2x))$, which has codimension 2 in $H^0(K_X^r)$ (at least if $r\geq 2$).